# Use replaceText() for selected text, not the entire element of a Google Document

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

How can I use `replaceText()` to replace a word in selected area of an element, the following code will replace matches in an entire element not the selected area. any ideas to fix this?

I know I can use `isPartial()` to separate partial selection but couldn't figure out how to replace the selected text.

```
function test() {
  var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
  if (!selection) {
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot find a selection in the document.');
    return;
  }

 var selectedElements = selection.getSelectedElements();
 for (var i = 0; i < selectedElements.length; ++i) {
  var selectedElement = selectedElements[i];
  //if (selectedElement.isPartial()) {
    selectedElement.getElement().asText().replaceText("alpha","beta");
    selectedElement.getElement().asText().replaceText("gamma","delta");
  //}
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
selectedElement.getElement().replaceText("alpha","beta");
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: This ignores the selection bounds and performs replacements in the entire element, which is explicitly not what the question is about.

Comment: @HenrikAndersson: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​How this isn't an answer? It's trying to answer the question.

Comment: @KevinGuan This is almost a year ago, I have no idea what I flagged at the time. Most likely it wasn't a solution at all. :)

Comment: @HenrikAndersson: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Oh, sorry, just noticed the date. But however, don't vote to delete but downvote and comment if you think an answer is incorrect by the way ;)

Comment: @KevinGuan Yeah, totes, as I said, if I flagged it then it must've been for a good reason at the time. If it was later edited I have no idea.

Comment: @HenrikAndersson: You can see whether the answer's been edited, when and how, in the log simply by clicking the link: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32471573/revisions

I couldn't comment because I didn't have enough reputation.  

KevinGuan: not agreeing with the answer is not a reason to downvote it. As you noted, the reason to downvote it is if it's NOT an attempt at the answer. Result: it's the ONLY attempted answer here to this question.